Include a 'post' block in a Jenkinsfile
I have two Jenkins pipelines with a common post block:
In first.Jenkinsfile I have
pipeline {
  ...

  post {
    ...
  } // end post
} // end pipeline

and in second.Jenkinsfile I have
pipeline {
  ...

  post {
    ...
  } // end post
} // end pipeline

What I'd like to do is hoist the common post block into a shared library, and have something like this:
def common_post = load 'post.groovy'
pipeline {
  ...

  common_post()
} // end pipeline

but I can't figure out how to do that. I have read through https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ and a bunch of stackoverflow questions that recommend shared libraries - but this is not what I'm looking for. I just want to inject a 'post' declarative chunk. I can't figure out how!

post block is defined in declarative pipeline syntax and what you are doing is a part of scripted pipeline. Those two can be mixed in very limited ways: either defining a whole declarative pipeline inside a shared library call method, or defining a custom step. post is neither. So, it's impossible to lift the entire post block, but you can lift logic inside its individual conditions:
pipeline {
...
  post {
    always {
      script {
        common_post_always()
      }
    }
  }
}

